# if statement not checking values as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an `if` statement checking if the value of a php check box is checked. For some reason it only stops at the `if` statement and wont run the `else`.

If I switch the rules of the `if` statement with the [initial] `else` statement I still only get the `if` statement.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // #Loader is inside of .LoaderContainer
    $('#Loader').on('inview', function(event, isInView) { 

        if (isInView) {

            // Pagination
            var nextPage = parseInt($('#pageno').val())+1;

            //Filters
            var minimum_wt = $('#hidden_minimum_wt').val();
            var maximum_wt = $('#hidden_maximum_wt').val();
            var shape = get_filter('shape'); // A checkbox
            var color = get_filter('color'); // A checkbox
            var enhancement = get_filter('enhancement'); // A checkbox
            var matching = get_filter('matching'); // A checkbox

            $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',
                url: 'vendors/php/NextPage.php',
                data: {
                    pageno: nextPage,
                    minimum_wt: minimum_wt,
                    maximum_wt: maximum_wt,
                    shape: shape,
                    color: color,
                    enhancement: enhancement,
                    matching: matching
                },
                success: function(data){

                    if(data != '') { // if any of values inside data are NOT empty

                        $('#StoneContainer').append(data);
                        $('.LoaderContainer').show();   //Show infinite scroll
                        $('#pageno').val(nextPage);


                    } else { // if any of the values in data are empty

                        $('#StoneContainer').append(data);
                        $('.LoaderContainer').hide();   //Hide infinite scroll

                    }

                }

            });

        }

    });

});
```

When there is no value to any one of the variables inside of `data` I want it to `hide` `.LoaderContainer`, otherwise I want it to `show` `.LoaderContainer`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202234/discussion-on-question-by-ariel-zabihi-if-statement-not-checking-values-as-expec).

Answer (score 0):

The `if` test should be around the call to `$.ajax()`, so you only send the AJAX request if any of the checkboxes are checked.

```
if (shape.length && color.length && enhancement.length && matching.length) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'vendors/php/NextPage.php',
    data: {
      pageno: nextPage,
      minimum_wt: minimum_wt,
      maximum_wt: maximum_wt,
      shape: shape,
      color: color,
      enhancement: enhancement,
      matching: matching
    },
    success: function(data) {

      if (data != '') { // if any of values inside data are NOT empty
        $('#StoneContainer').append(data);
        $('.LoaderContainer').show(); //Show infinite scroll
        $('#pageno').val(nextPage);
      } else { // if any of the values in data are empty
        $('#StoneContainer').append(data);
        $('.LoaderContainer').hide(); //Hide infinite scroll
      }
    }
  });
}
```